# Tensorflow Warning: "Gradients do not exist for variables" while computing gradients for a recurrent model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new to Tensorflow and I'm practicing using custom models by trying to write a BidirectionalLSTM. However, when training, the command line returns a warning that the Gradients do not exist for, from what I can tell, every variable in the model. The code for the class is the following:

```
class LSTMCell(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, hidden_layers):
        super(LSTMCell, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_layers = hidden_layers

        self.f = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layers, activation='sigmoid')
        self.i = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layers, activation='sigmoid')
        self.o = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layers, activation='sigmoid')
        self.Cprime = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layers, activation='tanh')
        

    def call(self, x, h, c, mask): 
        mask = tf.reshape(mask, (BATCH_SIZE, 1))
        input_x = np.concatenate((h, x), axis = 1)
        # print(input_x.shape)
        tf_mask = tf.matmul(mask, tf.ones([1, hidden_layers]))
        tf_inverse_mask = tf.ones([BATCH_SIZE, 1]) - mask
        tf_inverse_mask = tf.matmul(tf_inverse_mask, tf.ones([1, hidden_layers]))

        c = (self.f(input_x)*c + self.i(input_x)*self.Cprime(input_x))*tf_mask + c*tf_inverse_mask
        h = (self.o(input_x)*tf.math.tanh(c))*tf_mask + h*tf_inverse_mask

        return h, c

class BidirectionalLSTM(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, hidden_layers, outputLayer, encoder):
        super(BidirectionalLSTM, self).__init__()

        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(encoder.get_vocabulary()), hidden_layers, mask_zero=True)
        self.lstm1 = LSTMCell(hidden_layers)
        self.lstm2 = LSTMCell(hidden_layers)
        self.outputLayer = outputLayer
        self.outputDense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(outputLayer)
        self.outputFinal = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, input, length, mask):

        input = self.embedding(input)

        h1 = np.zeros([BATCH_SIZE, hidden_layers])
        h2 = np.zeros([BATCH_SIZE, hidden_layers])
        c1 = np.zeros([BATCH_SIZE, hidden_layers])
        c2 = np.zeros([BATCH_SIZE, hidden_layers])

        # mask.shape is [batch_size, length]
        for i in range(length):
            h1, c1 = self.lstm1(input[:, i, :], h1, c1, mask[:, i])
            h2, c2 = self.lstm2(input[:, length - i-1,:], h2, c2, mask[:, length-i-1])
        finalH = np.concatenate((h1, h2), axis = 1)
        lastNode = self.outputFinal(self.outputDense(finalH))

        return lastNode

bidLSTM = BidirectionalLSTM(hidden_layers, hidden_layers, encoder)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

# loss_function = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
for example, label in train_dataset:
    encoded_example = encoder(example).numpy()
    
    mask = create_mask(encoded_example)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = bidLSTM(encoded_example, encoded_example.shape[1], mask)
        loss = loss_function(label, predictions)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, bidLSTM.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, bidLSTM.trainable_variables)
```

I suspect this might have something to do with the fact that the model is recurrent, and Tensorflow needs to get the gradients of loss with respect to the weights in each cell and then sum it up (bptt). Is this the cause of the error, or is there perhaps something larger I'm missing? If it is the cause, what would be the workaround?

In the line of code where it says "for i in range(length)", I set length equal to 1, so there's no "recurrent" aspect of the model, and I still get the same error, so I suspect I'm missing something else here.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use numpy functions inside a Keras layer, you need to replace them with tensorflow functions

Comment: ah got it. thanks. Does the element-wise multiplication " * " operation I used in the "call" method of the LSTMCell need to be replaced with an equivalent tensorflow function as well?, or does that support elementwise multiplication of tensorflow objects as well?